# Как добавить нумерацию кода в Adobe Flash Builder 4.5?

Tags: flash

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить нумерацию кода в *Adobe Flash Builder 4.5 Premium*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правая кнопка мыши на серой полосе слева от текста, выбрать - "Show line numbers"